# Would an int variable containing another int variable be considered a reference type?

Tags: c#, value-type, reference-type

I understand that value types hold values directly (int, bool, etc.), while reference types (such as classes) hold references to where the values are stored. I haven't yet found an answer to this specific question in other posts regarding reference and value types.

```
int x = 10;
int y = x;

// Would y be considered a reference type?
```

I ask this because while "int x" is a value type, "y" doesn't hold a value directly, it "references" to "x" (a different location in memory).

Comment: `y` *does* hold a value - you just assigned it indirectly.  An integer type can only contain integer values never *another int variable*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would `y` be considered a reference type?

No.

Reference type vs. value type is a property of the *type itself*, not any of the variables of that type. Type `int` is a value type; therefore, all variables of type `int` are variables of a value type.

In your particular scenario, once `y` is assigned the value of `x`, it gets a *copy* of that value, not a reference to it. The values of `x` and `y` could be assigned independently of each other. If you subsequently change `x`, the value of `y` would remain unchanged:

```
int x = 10;
int y = x;
x = 5;
Console.WriteLine(y); // Prints 10
```

In contrast, variables of reference type "track" changes to the object that they reference:

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder("Hello");
StringBuilder y = x;
x.Append(", world");
Console.WriteLine(y); // Prints "Hello, world"
```

Answer (score 1):

> I ask this because while "int x" is a value type, "y" doesn't hold a value directly, it "references" to "x" (a different location in memory).

`y` does not reference to `x`. For **value** types, the assignment (via the `=` operator) means to *copy* the *value* from the variable on the right side to the variable on the left side.

For **reference** types, it means to copy the *reference*.